# If statement string data from dataframe does not work for larger years

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a problem with an if statement with my data from the dataframe. Somehow performing an if statement for years > 3years somehow all values larger than 9Y are not showing up and it is not clear why. The output looks like the following:

> ```
> 4Y
> 5Y
> 6Y
> 7Y
> 8Y
> 9Y
> 4Y
> 5Y
> 6Y
> 7Y
> 8Y
> 9Y
> ```

My code looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
['2015-02-09', '1Y',    2.241],
['2015-02-09', '1Y',    2.413],
['2015-02-09', '2Y',    2.228],
['2015-02-09', '2Y', 2.289],
['2015-02-09', '3Y', 2.263],
['2015-02-09', '3Y', 2.371],
['2015-02-09', '4Y', 2.413],
['2015-02-09', '5Y', 2.487],
['2015-02-09', '6Y', 2.578],
['2015-02-09', '7Y', 2.655],
['2015-02-09', '8Y', 2.74959],
['2015-02-09', '9Y', 2.81729],
['2015-02-09', '10Y',   2.853],
['2015-02-09', '12Y',   2.942],
['2015-02-09', '15Y',   3.047],
['2015-02-09', '20Y',   3.165],
['2015-02-09', '25Y',   3.225],
['2015-02-09','30Y',    3.225],
['2015-02-09', '1Y',    9.5],
['2015-02-09', '2Y',    8.75],
['2015-02-09', '3Y',    8.5],
['2015-02-09', '4Y',    8.13],
['2015-02-09', '5Y',    7.75],
['2015-02-09', '6Y',    7.63],
['2015-02-09', '7Y',    7.5],
['2015-02-09', '8Y',    7.45],
['2015-02-09','9Y',     7.25],
['2015-02-09', '10Y',   7.125],
['2015-02-09', '12Y',   7.08],
['2015-02-09', '15Y',   7.04],
['2015-02-09', '20Y',   6.435],
['2015-02-09', '25Y',   5.83],
['2015-02-09', '30Y',   5.45]
], columns=['date', 'year', 'values'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['year'] > '3Y':
        print(row['year'])
```

Comment: In lexicographic comparison "10" < "3". Try: `if int(row["year"][:-1]) > 3:`

Comment: Strings are compared lexicographically (in the alphabetic order). '10Y' is _less_ than '3Y', because '1' is less than '3'.

Comment: @ChristiFati, thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for! Could you please add it as answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem you compare strings lexicographically, so `10Y < 3Y`. Solution is convert values to integers.

```
df['mask'] = df['year'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int) > 3
```

---

```
print (df)
          date year   values   mask
0   2015-02-09   1Y  2.24100  False
1   2015-02-09   1Y  2.41300  False
2   2015-02-09   2Y  2.22800  False
3   2015-02-09   2Y  2.28900  False
4   2015-02-09   3Y  2.26300  False
5   2015-02-09   3Y  2.37100  False
6   2015-02-09   4Y  2.41300   True
7   2015-02-09   5Y  2.48700   True
8   2015-02-09   6Y  2.57800   True
9   2015-02-09   7Y  2.65500   True
10  2015-02-09   8Y  2.74959   True
11  2015-02-09   9Y  2.81729   True
12  2015-02-09  10Y  2.85300   True
13  2015-02-09  12Y  2.94200   True
14  2015-02-09  15Y  3.04700   True
15  2015-02-09  20Y  3.16500   True
16  2015-02-09  25Y  3.22500   True
17  2015-02-09  30Y  3.22500   True
18  2015-02-09   1Y  9.50000  False
19  2015-02-09   2Y  8.75000  False
20  2015-02-09   3Y  8.50000  False
21  2015-02-09   4Y  8.13000   True
22  2015-02-09   5Y  7.75000   True
23  2015-02-09   6Y  7.63000   True
24  2015-02-09   7Y  7.50000   True
25  2015-02-09   8Y  7.45000   True
26  2015-02-09   9Y  7.25000   True
27  2015-02-09  10Y  7.12500   True
28  2015-02-09  12Y  7.08000   True
29  2015-02-09  15Y  7.04000   True
30  2015-02-09  20Y  6.43500   True
31  2015-02-09  25Y  5.83000   True
32  2015-02-09  30Y  5.45000   True
```

Loop solution from comment of @CristiFati:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if int(row["year"][:-1]) > 3:
        print(row['year'])
```

Or with regex:

```
import re
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if int(re.search(r'\d+', row["year"]).group()) > 3:   
        print(row['year'])
```

Also is possible create integer column first:

```
df['year-int'] = df['year'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["year-int"] > 3:
        print(row['year'])
```

Comment: @jezarel, thanks a lot. How woul that work in the example shown above within the loop?

Comment: @MCM why do you want that for loop at all?

Comment: @JonClements, because I will have a more complex logic which makes it neccesarry looping through the rows. I found my answer above!

Comment: @MCM right, but you still can probably vectorize that logic - you should pretty much only loop in as a last resort - otherwise, you don't really get any advantage to using a dataframe over a list of lists.

Comment: @JonClements, how would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

Different rules apply on `>` sign when comparing `strings`. Try converting it into an `int` as a new column in dataframe and then printing the ones `> 3`.